# How can I make a reference plane to measure surface volume?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, elevation, tin, volume

I am looking to make a reference plane like the links below. I want to measure surface volume of an area in different elevation layer.

I just need to know how to make the reference plane in ArcGIS 10.1 !

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000037000000

Best,
Mahnoush

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the volume above or below a given reference plane you do *not* have to create a reference plane data set.

The reference plane is just the elevation (e.g. *250 meters*) of the plane.

In [Surface Volume (3D Analyst) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/) you have to specify this height as `base_z` parameter.

EDIT:
If you really want to create a reference plane data set you can use [Create Constant Raster (Spatial Analyst) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Constant_Raster/009z000000s4000000/).

Comment: Oh, ok I didn't know about this! Thanks a lot.

But I am a little confused ! for measuring the surface volume I have to make a Polygon Volume as well. I have problem with making this polygon over the TIN layer and define the different elevation for it ? 

Like the link above. for example I have a TIN surface which min contour is 25 m and max contour is 140 , then I want to measure all the surface above 25 m , 35m and ... ! 
I just wonder how to make this polygon on top ?

Comment: This is a new question. So I suggest that you start with a new question at /gis.stackexchange.com. Then you should give details about the software you have (3D Analyst, Spatial Analyst, …), about  the data you have (TIN, Raster, …) and  what you want to achieve exactly. Describe the target you want to achieve.